# Georeference a JPEG image knowing some random x,y point geocoordinates and CRS

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff, rasterio

I have an orthomosaic GeoTIFF generated by a big number of JPG images (StructureFromMotion algorithm) that are not georeferenced. With computer vision I find some points on the initial orthophoto.tif file  that are actually the same points with the points in each JPG image I want to georeference. Given the CRS of the TIFF file is known, how can I georeference the JPG images since I have these {x, y, geocoord_x, geocoord_y} points?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add some ground control points (GCPs) and use GDAL to figure out the extent of the file and so on.

You should do this on a copy of your original file in case you screw things up, and I assume that you have your GCPs available somewhere (e.g. a Pandas dataframe, but whatever).

Below, I assume the spatial reference is XXXX, so that needs updating.

```py
from osgeo import gdal, osr

def update_gcp(df, fname):
    """Update the file with GCPs stored in dataframe"""

    # Open file in update mode
    ds = gdal.Open(fname, gdal.GA_Update)
    # Set spatial reference for the file (if not there)
    sr = osr.SpatialReference()
    sr.ImportFromEPSG(XXXX) #XXX is the projection of your points

    # Now, let's say you have your ground control points in a pandas
    # dataframe. Basically:
    # 1. Map coordinates easting
    # 2. Map coordinates northing
    # 3. Map elevation
    # 4. Column
    # 5. Row

    gcps = [gdal.GCP(df.x_map, df.y_map, df.z, df.i_pix, df.j_pix),
            for j, row in df.iterrows()]

    # The following bit updates the dataset with the GCPs and projection
    # information
    ds.SetGCPs(gcps, sr.ExportToWkt())

    # Remember to close the file
    ds = None
```

Comment: Best regards man i did the same and i was just about to post the same answer as i really didn't know about gcp's and gdal_transate.Sadly features are not reliable for every image so i go ahead with orthorectificating the image.Thx anyway.